# Node.js - mongoose promises - loop through

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a trouble with mongoose used with node.js. In my model I am having only group supervisor's ID, and in this route I want also to add supervisorName to variable (this name is stored in Group model). So, yeah, I've read some about promises, but still, I dont have any idea how to solve that. (Basically, I just want to loop through all groups, get their models from mongodb, and assign supervisor name to every group)

```
router.get('/manage', function(req, res, next) {
Group.find({}, function(err, groups) {
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
        Group.findById(group.supervisor, function(err, supervisor) {
            group.supervisorName = supervisor.name;
            console.log(supervisor.name);
        });
    });
}).then(function() {
    res.render('groups/groups_manage', {groups : groups});
});
});
```

Comment: One more information, supervisor is another group ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` your groups array into array of `promises` and use `Promise.all` to resolve them all.

```
router.get('/manage', function(req, res, next) {
    Group.find({})
    .exec() // 1
    .then(groups => {
        return Promise.all(groups.map(group => { // 2, 3
            return Group.findById(group.supervisor)
            .exec()
            .then((supervisor) => { // 4
                group.supervisorName = supervisor.name;
                return group;
            });
        }));
    })
    .then(propGroups => {
        res.render('groups/groups_manage', {groups : popGroups});
    });
});
```

#### Explanations:

1. Mongoose Model methods supports both callbacks and promises interface. However to use the promise interface we need to use the `exec` method and remove the callbacks.
2. `Promise.all` takes an array of promises. It waits for all of them to resolve and any of them to reject (give error). *Note: The promises are executed in parallel*
3. We have an array of `group` objects, we map them into promises. Calling `.findById` and again using `exec` to get a promise from it. **Note: Remember to return your promises**
4. We update the object, and return it as the final result of promise.

Comment: Woah, you made my day, can you explain why i need to do this that way? (Any comments on code or something please?)

Comment: Would you please add how to handle two operations? For example `findById` and counting how often this element is referenced in another collection, through `OtherModel.countDocuments`?